# Cloud Run Cloud SQL VPC Connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I am trying to connect the VPC that I created in my Gcloud, to connect Cloud Run with Cloud SQL. However, when connecting Cloud Run to the VPC, the connection menu is not visible.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMi22.jpg)

I need to connect my serverless instance on Cloud Run to my SQL Server instance on Cloud SQL

Comment: Did you create a VPC serverless connector? Did you created it in the correct region (same as Cloud Run service)? Did you have a look to direct VPC egress feature on Cloud Run?

Comment: It is in the same region as Cloud Run and Cloud SQL, the VPC was able to connect to Cloud Run but cannot connect to Cloud SQL:  `{
insertId: "6512f0ad0004f2ffb3c5fde9"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/moonlit-buckeye-399801/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-09-26T14:54:37.330551482Z"
resource: {2}
textPayload: "SQL Connection Error: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.127.112.4:1433 in 15000ms"
timestamp: "2023-09-26T14:54:37.324351Z"
}`

Comment: Did you open the firewall rules?